# Node.js / Express / JavaScript scope issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, scope

I'm working on the following Node.js webapp, with handlebars and express for templating and routing.
But a problem arises in the `app.get('/', function(){ ... })` block.

The problem is that when it runs, it says it `Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\natha\Documents\GitHub\HAS\webUI\app.js:19:23)`

```
var port     = 3000,
fs       = require('fs'),
exec     = require('child_process'),
express  = require("express"),
exphbs   = require("express3-handlebars"),
app      = express(),
Database = require('./db/Database.js'),
db       = new Database().selectDB('lights')
hbs      = exphbs.create({ defaultLayout: 'main'});


app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine','handlebars');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port))
app.enable('view cache');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/',function(request, response){
    var data = this.db.getData();
    response.render('home', {
        helpers: {
           client: data.clients
        }
    });
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    updateClients();



    socket.on('news', function(data, error){
        console.log(this.db);
    }.bind(this));
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        updateClients();
        console.log('hi');
    });

}.bind(this));

var updateClients = function(){
    var clients = [];
    io.sockets.clients().forEach(function(data){
        clients.push(data.id);
    });

    io.sockets.emit('news', { 
        users: clients
    });
}
```

I'm 100% sure it's not a asynchronous function problem, because when the `socket.on('news', ....)` runs which is triggered by a client far after the DB has initialized, it successfully prints the database info including the data..

This has to be a scope issue but I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: Maybe you mean `db` instead of `this.db`?

Comment: Apparently I did something stupid... I had to call the `setDB` after initializing the `new Database()` .. Now that I think about it, it makes sense. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `this`, db is just a variable, so it should be `db.getData()`

Comment: Apparently I did something stupid... I had to call the `setDB` after initializing the `new Database()` .. Now that I think about it, it makes sense. thanks anyway :)

Comment: @NathanPrins Happens! The one thing that's tricky about JavaScript is keeping track of what `this` is at any given moment.